# TeamCity building specific branch on pull request

Tags: git, teamcity

I have a solution that consists of several projets like this:

```
MySolution
-Project1
-Project2
-Project3
```

For each project I have a branch on github, for example Project1Branch, Project2Branch... I have configured triggers on teamcity for builing containers on pullrequest into master. But when it happens all three projects are build, though changes are made only in Projeсt1. I tried to configure branch filter in triggers for build step `+:Project1*` but in doesn't work.
How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR**

- Leave your **Trigger** branch filters to `+:*`.
- In the **Pull Requests** build feature, configure the "source" to `Project1Branch` and "target" to `master` branches.
- Keep your **VCS** configuration minimal (see below).

---

For `Project1` to build at each MR of `Project1Branch` into `master` :

Only watch the `Project1Branch` branch. In your **VCS configuration** :

- **Default branch:** `refs/heads/Project1Branch`
- (optional unless you need branch-filtered build steps) **Branch specification:** `Project1Branch`

Add the `merge-request/...` branches that match your pattern to the watched branches. **Pull Request Filtering** :

- **By source branch:** `+:refs/heads/Project1Branch`
- **By target branch:** `+:refs/heads/master`

Trigger on every change in watched branch. **Triggers** :

- **Branch filters:** `+:*`

If you **only** want to trigger on MR branches, do **Triggers** :

- **Branch filters:**

```
+:*
-:Project1Branch
```

The same goes for `Project2` and `Project3`.